# Looping through and comparing values in 2 dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes that I need to loop through.

```
Df1[1:5,]

  year month      Vol
1 2015     7 4.82e-05
2 2015     6 5.91e-05
3 2015     5 6.56e-05
4 2015     4 6.10e-05
5 2015     3 7.85e-05

Df2[1:5,]

  year month IB
1 2015     7  0
2 2015     4  1
3 2015     3  0
4 2015     6  1
5 2015     5  0
```

I need to loop through `DF1`, compare the months from `DF1` and `DF2`, and if they are the same then set `DF1$IB<-DF2$IB`. I tried using `sapply`, but I get this error

```
tmp<-sapply(DF1$month,function(x){if(DF2$month==x){
DF1$IB<-DF2$IB
}})

Warning messages:
1: In if (DF2$month == x) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
.....
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Otherwise I would have to resort to multiple for loops, and since `DF1` is 900K rows long and `DF2` is 300 rows long, that seems very inefficient to me.

Comment: Have you tried `merge`?

Comment: What if they are not equal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the latest version ([see here how to install v1.9.5 from GH](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation)) you don't need to set keys and just need `setDT(df1)[df2, on = c("year","month")]` which add the `IB`, this gives:

```
   year month      Vol IB
1: 2015     7 4.82e-05  0
2: 2015     4 6.10e-05  1
3: 2015     3 7.85e-05  0
4: 2015     6 5.91e-05  1
5: 2015     5 6.56e-05  0
```

---

Supposing that the `year`/`month` are not equal for both datasets, you have to join differently:

```
setDT(df2)[df1, on = c("year","month")]
```

which gives:

```
   year month IB      Vol
1: 2015     7  0 4.82e-05
2: 2015     6  1 5.91e-05
3: 2015     5  0 6.56e-05
4: 2015     4  1 6.10e-05
5: 2015     3 NA 7.85e-05
```

Used data for second example:

```
df1 <- structure(list(year = c(2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L), month = c(7L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 3L), Vol = c(4.82e-05, 5.91e-05, 6.56e-05, 6.1e-05, 7.85e-05)), .Names = c("year", "month", "Vol"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"))
df2 <- structure(list(year = c(2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L), month = c(7L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 5L), IB = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L)), .Names = c("year", "month", "IB"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"))
```

Comment: For the record I'm well aware of the features of 1.9.5. I made a conscious decision not to use them because they are no needed in this case (they do not improve speed). Also, 1.9.5 is not stable, and you did not show how to install it.

Comment: @jlhoward I didn't mean to say you are not aware of v1.9.5. In my experience 1.9.5 is just as stable as 1.9.4, moreover it solves quite some bugs. Furthermore, I provided a link to the installation instructions, but will make that more clear. Hence, I don't see a reason to downvote.

Comment: Let me put it this way. In those cases where I come up with a minor improvement on someone else's answer, I post it as a comment to that answer (or a suggestion), or, in very rare cases, and edit to that answer. You're right about one thing though, this is only the second time I've down-voted anything on SO. I find the practice offensive, but there are limits.

Comment: @jlhoward I was thinking about posted a comment. But when it became too long, I decided to post as an alternative answer as I'm hesitant to edit answers of others extensively. If you are ok with it, I will edit your answer with my alternative.

Comment: Changing this particular answer would just create confusion, but in future, [that seems to be the purpose of edits](http://stackoverflow.com/help/editing). BTW: Edit means "add an alternative", not "change the original answer".

Comment: @jlhoward Thanx, I will keep that in mind for next time.

Answer (score 3):

If your Df1 is that large data.tables might be better than merge.

```
library(data.table)
setkey(setDT(Df1),year,month)[setDT(Df2),IB:=IB]
Df1
#    year month      Vol IB
# 1: 2015     3 7.85e-05  0
# 2: 2015     4 6.10e-05  1
# 3: 2015     5 6.56e-05  0
# 4: 2015     6 5.91e-05  1
# 5: 2015     7 4.82e-05  0
```

So this converts `Df1` to a data.table in indexes it on year and month, then does a data.table join on `Df2` (also converted to a data.table), then adds the `IB` column from `Df2` to `Df1`.

Using a more realistic example:

```
set.seed(1)
Df1 <- data.frame(year=rep(2015,1e6),
                  month=sample(3:7,1e6,replace=TRUE),
                  Vol=rnorm(1e6))
system.time(result.mrg <- merge(Df1,Df2,by=c("year","month")))
#   user  system elapsed 
#   11.8     0.0    11.8 

system.time(result.dt  <- setkey(setDT(Df1),year,month[setDT(Df2),IB:=IB])
#    user  system elapsed 
#    0.07    0.00    0.06 

identical(result.mrg$IB, result.dt$IB)
# [1] TRUE
```